# Help understanding Window anatomy

Tags: windows, construction

I'm renovating my basement, which has one double-hung vinyl window (pictured). I want to add one more on the same wall and trying to get a close match. The windows in this house were replaced in 2007 (manufacturer is Vista).

My question is with the frame around the window, which I assume is from the original construction of the house (1991). I see it is on a window sill, with some kind of frame integrated with it. What is that, do I need to buy that in addition to a new window?

I don't want to damage the siding on the outside of the house, so I was planning to buy a replacement window (not new construction).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original window sash, and not the jamb, were replaced with a window replacement insert, to keep the look the same, you need to do some fabricating.

All this is dependent upon if you can find an exact replacement unit to match the one installed in 2007. The chance of that.... maybe. Window manufactures make changes to their product over time. Your window is possibly not in production anymore, but the next generation of window that carries the same size and some the details is what would now be available. Again, this is only a possibility.

What you will need to buy in addition, and this will be much, much more unlikely, is the wood window unit that matches the original one to the house when it was built in 1991. If you do, you would still need to throw away the operable sashes of that unit and install just the jamb. A big expense just to throw away a major part of it.

If it were me, I would get the materials to make a new wood jamb to match the one installed in 1991.

Construction details for wood window jambs are really quite basic construction. A tablesaw and miter box is all that is needed for tools along with drill and screwgun.
Priming everything before assembly would be essential.

The brick mold on the outside of the window may be the only other part difficult to match exactly. All are basically the same size, but there are minor detailing differences from one supplier to the next. Some folks don't worry over this too much since the differences are so small.

Answer (score 1):

The outer frame looks like custom millwork. Whoever architected the house just made a millwork design and the developer had it fabricated. He said I am building 20 houses and so I need 120 window frames like this and he hands the millwork company the architect's design. The architect makes the design match the dimensions of his vinyl windows exactly. That way they fit.

Your problem is now you have to reproduce all this one off, which means it will be expensive.

The "standard" solution would be to go to a cabinetry carpenter and tell him to reproduce the frame. This will not be cheap, but is your best option unless you want to do the millwork yourself, which I would not recommend attempting unless you are an experienced carpenter.

To get the window is easy. Just find a supplier that has that exact size of vinyl window. It might take a little calling around.

BTW, fake window lattices are so cheesy, I would get rid of those.